# Cartesian plane for 3 cards and 4cards of deck in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The following code runs for 2cards of a deck and gives cartesian plane such that no duplicates are there.

```
   allcards = [minBound..maxBound] :: [Card]
   cartesianplane=[ [x ,y] | x <- allcards, y <- allcards, x < y ]
```

How can I do the same for 3 cards and 4cards such that no duplicates are there.

Comment: Changing the minimum amount of code structure, `[[x, y, z] | x <- allcards, y <- allcards, z <- allcards, x < y, y < z]`

Comment: There are dozens of examples of questions about generating sets and combinations of a list if you use the search function

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to recursively generate the sets:

```
-- an example set of cards:
data Card = A | T | J | Q | K
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

next intv a
  | a == maxBound = []
  | otherwise     = intv (succ a)

interval a = [ a .. ]
interval2 a = [ [x,y] | x <- interval a, y <- next interval x ]
interval3 a = [ x:y | x <- interval a, y <- next interval2 x ]
interval4 a = [ x:y | x <- interval a, y <- next interval3 x ]
interval5 a = [ x:y | x <- interval a, y <- next interval4 x ]
```

E.g.:

```
interval A = [A,T,J,Q,K]
interval2 A = [[A,T],[A,J],[A,Q],[A,K],[T,J],[T,Q],[T,K],[J,Q],[J,K],[Q,K]]
interval3 A = [[A,T,J],[A,T,Q],[A,T,K],[A,J,Q],[A,J,K],[A,Q,K],[T,J,Q],[T,J,K],[T,Q,K],[J,Q,K]]
interval4 A = [[A,T,J,Q],[A,T,J,K],[A,T,Q,K],[A,J,Q,K],[T,J,Q,K]]
interval5 A = [[A,T,J,Q,K]]
```